# Redirecting Terminal Output of Running Process

Tags: linux, input, ssh, terminal, output

I am connecting to a server using SSH and running a minecraft server there with

```
java -jar server.jar
```

Now, i want to be able to close my SSH session without closing the minecraft server and, if i need to type some commands to the server or read the server output, i want to be able to re-connect with SSH and get the output and input back to my terminal window.

Is this possible? I've read about redirecting the output to a file, but that won't solve my problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use screen to detach and reattach the window.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-a-minecraft-server-on-linux